# Is there an equivalent of raw for displaying haml stored in an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In `/views/documents/show.html.haml`, I have:

```
= raw @document.content
```

If @document.content stores HTML, such as `<p>foo</p>`, I see "foo" formatted as a paragraph.

But if `@document.content` stores HAML, such as `%p foo`, I see the entered code, rather than "foo" formatted as a paragraph.

The same happens if I use...

```
   = @document.content
```

...without the `raw`.

Is there a solution?

Comment: You have to process HAML yourself in this case. Turn it into HTML which you already know how to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was:

```
- engine = Haml::Engine.new(@document.content)
= engine.render
```